# How to resolve the ls >file.txt dumps garbage charecters in linux?

Tags: linux

[image]When i do `ls` in my terminal it works fine, but when I do `ls>somefile` it dumps garbage values along the name.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy the output into a code block.

Comment: Add the output of `type -a ls` to the question, please.

Comment: my guess is that the command is aliased as `ls --color`. you either have to unalias it, run it as `command ls` or run the executable as `/bin/ls` (or wherever it resides)

Answer (score 2):

Your `ls` command is aliased to something like `ls --color=auto` (or 'yes') which produces the ANSI coloring codes you see.

There are a few possible solutions:

- You could unalias it with `unalias ls` which would remove the colors from your `ls` output.
- Specify that you don't want color as `ls --color=no` in your command.

Comment: Thanks.. yes that was the issue. I removed the alias and it is working fine.